# Trying to Execute my Eggplant Scrips using CMD, But shown with warning message as "The -compare: method for NSObject is deprecated"

Tags: cmd, eggplant

I am working on Eggplant Functional tool and I have a main script, from there I will trigger the execution usually. through tool I can able to execute it properly. Was trying to execute it using command prompt. Please find below command that I used to execute it from CMD:

```
"C:\Program Files\eggPlant\runscript.bat" "D:\KeringSuite\KeringPOS_Release2_EMEA_IT.suite\Scripts\Main.script"
```

Here i am facing issue and scripts are not getting executed. Here is the **error**:

> 2019-05-15 12:34:22.429 runscript[11140:9728] WARNING - unable to create shared user defaults!
>   2019-05-15 12:34:22.429 runscript[11140:9728] NSDocumentClass EGGDocument not NS Document subclass
>   2019-05-15 12:34:23.256 runscript[11140:9728] Eggplant (Command Line) is 18.2.1-Windows-64, build (1811131049), on Windows 6.1
>   2019-05-15 12:34:24.893 runscript[11140:9728] RLM: Initialized. Local license folder: C:/Users/sabitha.adama/Application Data/Eggplant
>   2019-05-15 12:34:29.230 runscript[11140:9728] Approved License: 
>   Eggplant (18.2.1-1811131049) running in Execution mode on Windows-64 Host:0x00ff5ac0ac10
>   2019-05-15 12:34:30.650 runscript[11140:7008] Load C:\Program Files\Eggplant\Eggplant.app\Resources\ABBYY\Bin\FREngine.dll
>   2019-05-15 12:34:30.650 runscript[11140:7008] Successfully loaded FREngine.dll
>   2019-05-15 12:34:31.414 runscript[11140:7008] OCR enabled-unlimited usage
>   2019-05-15 12:34:40.904 runscript[11140:9512] Execution of the script located at path: D:/KeringSuite/KeringPOS_Release2_EMEA_IT.suite/Scripts/Main.script STARTED
>   2019-05-15 12:34:40.951 runscript[11140:9512] File NSObject+GNUstepBase.m: 50. In -[NSObject(GNUstepBase) compare:] WARNING: The -compare: method for NSObject is deprecated.
>   2019-05-15 12:34:41.075 runscript[11140:9512] Unable To Lock SuiteInfo file - Could not save EggplantCommon.suite.
>   Error: 13
>   If your file system does not support file locking please use:defaults write Eggplant SuiteLockingEnabled NO
>   [12:34:58:000] [11140:000021a4] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
>   [12:35:02:899] [11140:000021a4] [INFO][com.freerdp.gdi] - Local framebuffer format  PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA32
>   [12:35:02:899] [11140:000021a4] [INFO][com.freerdp.gdi] - Remote framebuffer format PIXEL_FORMAT_RGB16
>   2019-05-15 12:35:02.914 runscript[11140:8612] Connection with GG STARTED. TYPE:RDP
>   2019-05-15 12:36:43.470 runscript[11140:9512] Execution of the script located at path: D:/KeringSuite/KeringPOS_Release2_EMEA_IT.suite/Scripts/Main.script ENDED
>   2019-05-15 12:36:43.470 runscript[11140:9728] reported exception -  NAME:Script Failed REASON:Script Error:
>   Number of Errors logged: 2 INFO:{OtherButton = ""; }
>   2019-05-15 12:36:45.508 runscript[11140:9728] Completed KeringPOS_Release2_EMEA_IT.suite - Main.script
>   2019-05-15 12:36:45.649 runscript[11140:8612] Connection with GG CLOSED. TYPE: RDP

Please help on this...

Answer (score 0):

The error log states the problem

> Unable To Lock SuiteInfo file - Could not save EggplantCommon.suite.
>   Error: 13

and a solution

> If your file system does not support file locking please use:defaults
>   write Eggplant SuiteLockingEnabled NO

More in-depth info is available at eggplant forum http://forums.testplant.com/discussion/2255/connecting-to-vnc-via-execution-licenses

Answer (score 0):

```
-CommandLineOutput yes -host ****-port 3389 -username ****-password **** -type rdp -DefaultHeight 1080 -DefaultWidth 1920 -GlobalResultsFolder "specify the path here" -LicenseHost **** -reportfailure yes
```

Try adding the above parameters when running from command line